# Highcharts in Joomla 2.5

Tags: jquery, joomla, highcharts

Good morning,

Today I tried to use "Highcharts" in my Joomla 2.5 but I can't make it work. It has to be something related to the JQuery (I think) but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I'm also using "JQueryEasy" plugin in order to avoid a conflict between JQuery versions but the page is broken when I try to put the chart in the Joomla page.

That's my JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/plugins/system/jqueryeasy/jquerynoconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then, the Highchart is trying to use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to use different chart applications but they didn't work, and now I really want this to work because the charts are really good, but I don't know the error because I can't see any error in my website.

I will be much appreciated if you can help me with that,

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: `That's my JQuery` >> Do you mean this is what is showing in the browser inspector or it's what you have manually typed in?

Comment: That JQuery is showing in the browser inspector. Thanks Lodder.

Comment: You are including second jQuery for Highcharts only? It's not required. Just make sure that you are creating chart after page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, so I have to delete the second JQuery? And how can I see if the chart is created after the page is loaded? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason to includejQuery twice. And read abour jQuery.ready() [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).